# Mixed-breeds are puzzles too!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, masyu

This is a three-dimensional mixed-breed puzzle. The five squares depict the five layers of a $5\times5\times5$ cube. The goal is to solve the odd-numbered layers as [yajilin](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/yajilin.html) and even-numbered layers as [masyu](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html).

Short rules:

- Shade some cells on odd-numbered layers. The numbered cells show how many shaded cells are in the direction of the arrow.
- Shaded cells cannot be adjacent to another shaded cell, but they can touch the numbered cells.
- Unshaded cells on each yajilin layer are all connected in 2D (i.e. each layer is treated separately).
- Make a single loop in 3D space which goes through every **unshaded cell** on odd-numbered layers, and every **circle** on even-numbered layers.
- A line passing through a white circle must continue straight through its cell and make a turn in the directly following or preceding cell (or both).
- A line passing through a black circle must make a turn inside that cell and continue straight for at least one cell on both sides.

**Note**: Feel free to use any notation you feel the most comfortable with, as long as it's properly explained. [My way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3oGT.png) is to use diagonal lines to show movement between layers.

> [image]

Comment: Just a 3d Yajalin left to do :) (I was thinking about the arrows, you could use NESWUD)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Maybe I'll try that next!

Comment: Or even a 4d Masyu!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A step-by-step solution follows. Click on pictures for a full-size version. Layer #1 is the "top", so moving towards it is going "Z-up".

Step 1:

> **Layer #1**. The 0 clues allow many cells to be designated unshaded (I use blue for this purpose). Then, there is only one way to resolve the cluster of 1 clues and retain connectivity of unshaded cells. Finally, the dead ends must go Z-down.
>
>  [image: Step 1]

Step 2:

> **Layer #2**. The shading of several of the cells in layer #3's R1-2 can be determined by connectivity logic. Now layer #2 can use information from #1 and #3. R1C3's line cannot go Z-up, so must go left and right. R2C5 cannot go Z-down, so it goes left and Y-down. The dangling end in R1C1 must go Y-down.
>
>  [image: Step 2]

Step 3:

> **Black circles**. In layer #4, R2C4 cannot go Z-up, so it goes left and Y-down. R4C3 and then R5C3 can only go Z-up and left; in R5C3's case its line hits into a white circle and keeps going. Now layer #2's R5C4 can only go Z-down and Y-up.
>
>  [image: Step 3]

Step 4:

> **Layer #3**. R4-5 have their shading forced. Then R3C5 and R2C4 cannot go Z so they go left and Y-down. This forces the last shaded square in R2's 2 clue, which forces R1C2 to go right and Z-down. Finally, R4C2 must go Z-up and Y-up.
>
>  [image: Step 4]

Step 5:

> **Maysu cleanup**. Layer #2's R3C2 must go right and Y-up. The dangling end in R2C1 must go Y-down. Layer #4's R1C4, R3C5, and R1C5 cannot go Z, forcing connections. The dangling end in R5C1 cannot go Z and so goes Y-up
>
>  [image: Step 5]

Step 6:

> **Layer #5**. R5C5 is shaded because if not, it would be forced to go Z-up and violate the white circle in R4C5. Connectivity unshading above. The new dangling end must go Z-up, which then forces the dangling end in Layer #3's R4C5 to go Z-up.
>
>  [image: Step 6]

Step 7:

> **Layer #1**. Crosses are where Z movement is impossible. R5C5 must be shaded because any line put there would dead-end. Then several things are forced: the R4-5C3-4 curve, going straight through R2C4, and having R5C2 go Z-down and Y-up.
>
>  [image: Step 7]

Step 8:

> **Layer #2**. R4C3 goes left because Z-up would form a loop. R5C1-2 can't go Z, so they are forced around the corner. Additionally, a few more Xs for layer #1.
>
>  [image: Step 8]

Step 9:

> **Layer #5**. R3C1 cannot be shaded as then the C5 2 clue would isolate an unshaded cell. IT can't go Z, so it is forced to go right and Y-up. Connectivity & clues determine shading. Now the loop in this layer can be determined, with helper Xs to guide the forced lines.
>
>  [image: Step 9-1]
>
>  [image: Step 9-2]

Step 10:

> **Layers #4 & #3**. R3C1 cannot go Y-up and so goes Z-up and right. The dangling end in R2C1 cannot go Y-up, so it goes right. The dangling end in R1C3 is forced Z-up. As a bonus, layer #3's loop parts can be finished; note the two helper Xs added in as guides.
>
>  [image: Step 10-2]

Step 11:

> **Finish**. First, both dangling ends in layer #2 are forced to go to layer #1. Then, with some more helper Xs, loop connectivity forces layer #1's lines, and its last shaded cell.
>
>  [image: Step 11-1]

Solution (with helper Xs removed):

> [image: Solution]

Answer (score 7):

Observations

> The Masyu layers behave like they do in the previous 3D variants.
>  The usual Yajilin rules of dead ends only apply when the layer above and below is blocked as well. The 2D-connectivity allows easy deductions.

Finished grid

> [image]